# Drop table in lake database

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

As print in screen below, why i can not drop this table in my lake databse ? i have create this table directly from my sink in my dataflow, thanks

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to drop this from a Notebook.

```
%%pyspark

spark.sql("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Database1.DivideTest")
```

Comment: you always have to go through a notebook for this kind of operation ?

Comment: According to Microsoft documentation, "Tables in the lake databases cannot be modified from a serverless SQL pool. Use the Database designer or Apache Spark pools to modify a lake database."

Comment: Yes:  only in a Notebook.  However, within a Notebook, it can be done with `%%pyspark` as above, or just `%%sql`:  `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS db1.tbl`